# WildFly 10 Remote EJB invocation using JNDI ClassNotFoundException javax.ejb.EJBException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jndi, wildfly-10

I have Java 8 & WildFly (JBoss) 10.0 installed. I have deployed the `emsa.jar` file with a remote EJB in it on the "remote" server.

I am attempting to use JNDI to invoke a method in the EJB from within a separate client app by running the client's main method as a Java App in Eclipse, but am getting the following error:

```
INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@61f8bee4, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <545ebbdd>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=skb]} on channel Channel ID d234d46a (outbound) of Remoting connection 395b72b3 to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
Exception in thread "naming-client-message-receiver-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBException
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.SerializedEJBInvocationHandler.readResolve(SerializedEJBInvocationHandler.java:110)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.SerializedEJBInvocationHandler.readResolve(SerializedEJBInvocationHandler.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadResolve(SerializableClass.java:417)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1299)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:213)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNestedObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:169)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1254)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:213)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:45)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:156)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.BaseProtocolCommand.readResult(BaseProtocolCommand.java:59)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleClientMessage(Protocol.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver$1.run(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to invoke lookup, status=WAITING
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:98)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:276)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:132)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.kelly_ann.employeemgmt.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

The code in the client's Main class is:

```
package com.k_a.employeemgmt;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.k_a.employeemgmt.EmployeeMgmtService;
import com.k_a.employeemgmt.domain.Employee;

public class Main {

    // this remotely invokes the server's EmployeeMgmtService.getAllEmployees() method.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
            jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
            jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
            System.out.println("MYTESTjndiProperties: " + jndiProperties); // gets here
            Context jndi = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
            System.out.println("MYTESTjndi: " + jndi); // gets here

            EmployeeMgmtService service = (EmployeeMgmtService)jndi.lookup("emsa/EmployeeMgmtImpl!com.k_a.employeemgmt.EmployeeMgmtService");
            System.out.println("MYTESTservice: " + service); // doesn't get to here
            List<Employee> employees = service.getAllEmployees();
            for(Employee employee : employees) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }
        }
```

My client application's Gradle build file (`build.gradle`) has the following dependencies in it:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'compileJava', 'test', 'jar'

jar {
    archiveName = "emtc.jar"
}

test.useJUnit()

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'jboss:jboss-client:4.0.2'
    compile 'org.jboss:jboss-remote-naming:2.0.4.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:3.3.6.Final'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have tried following the WildFly/JBoss docs [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project) for the last day but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final solution:**

The issue was my Gradle build.gradle file I needed to apply the `'application'` plugin listed [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and call the `'run'` task. Once that was done it worked like a charm!  Ended up using the maven repository BOM (from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-ejb-client-bom)) in Gradle build file too since that was the best way to ensure proper dependency management.  Thanks for all the help!  Much appreciated.  :-)

Final code in the `build.gradle` file is below:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'compileJava', 'test', 'jar', 'run'

mainClassName = 'com.k_a.employeemgmt.Main'

jar {
    archiveName = "emtc.jar"
}

test.useJUnit()

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.wildfly:wildfly-ejb-client-bom:10.0.0.Final'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small [tutorial](http://letsprog.com/ejb-3-2-standalone-client/) about the way to do in Maven for Wildfly 9.0.2.Final. So I just tried to translate it into the Gradle way (sorry I have no experience with Gradle) and I have adapted the dependencies to conform with Wildfly 10.0.0.Final respecting your need so that you wouldn't get NoClassDefException if any bad versions combination :

```
dependencies {
    org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
    org.jboss:jboss-remote-naming:2.0.4.Final
    org.jboss:jboss-ejb-client:2.1.4.Final
    org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:3.3.4.Final
    org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:1.4.10.Final
    org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
}
```

Or just use :

```
dependencies {
    org.wildfly:wildfly-client-all:10.0.0.Final
}
```

But in the second case, you would have other transitive dependencies for JMS...

By the way, in the Maven way, I often use a BOM dependency which will imply automatically the "right" versions for the dependencies, but I don't know if there is something similar in Gradle. If it is possible you can use this BOM :

```
org.wildfly:wildfly-ejb-client-bom:10.0.0.Final
```

And then you can omit the versions for the dependencies I mentioned above.

Let me have your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the wildfly-ejb-client-bom!  That helped a lot.

The issue was my Gradle build.gradle file I needed to apply the application plugin and call the 'run' task. Once that was done it worked like a charm!